# Xubuntu 14.04 for my laptop

Tags: xubuntu

Just a problem from my old lap - Dell Latitude D430 : 1.3 Ghz Core 2 Duo, 2GB Ram.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 just last week , but it was very slow when i run any applications.

And I found that Xubuntu is much better performance than Ubuntu on old lap. 
So i download Xubuntu 14.04 . will it better performance on my laptop ? or i have to download the older Xubuntu or using Lubuntu ?

Comment: Almost any version will do. k/x/lubuntu , choose the DE you prefer. On older machines I prefer KDE (kubuntu) , YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any DVDs or a USB without anything useful on it laying around? If so, you could always make a Live CD/Live USB and check. Make sure your computer loads USB/CD/DVD before your hard drive (If not you will have to change it in the BIOS) and click Try Ubuntu/Xubuntu instead of Install.